# How to say XAML <Button Height="Auto"/> in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, autosize

How can you set `Height="*"` and `Height="Auto"` in code behind?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For setting `Height = "Auto"` on most controls, you want to assign the value with `double.NaN`.

Example:

```
element.Height = double.NaN;
```

Setting `Width/Height = "*"` ( is a slightly different matter, since it only applies to a select few elements (`ColumnDefinition` and `RowDefinition` for example). The type of the `Width`/`Height` value is [`GridLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.aspx), rather than `double`.

Example (more are given on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype.aspx):

```
column1.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto); // Auto
column2.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star); // *
```