# How to reset the Image.Width and Image.Height to auto in code-behind?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

In Xaml code, I set the width and height of an Image to Auto. Then, in code-behind, I sometime have to set it to different values. But how can I set it back to Auto in codebehind?

This is how it looks in the xaml code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image x:Name="FlickrImage"/>
```

And in codebehind:

```
FlickrImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/error_image.png", UriKind.Relative));               
            FlickrImage.Width = 128;
            FlickrImage.Height = 128;
```

But after this, I want to set it back to Auto. Can anyone please give me a hand?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to say XAML <Button Height="Auto"/> in code behind?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497921/how-to-say-xaml-button-height-auto-in-code-behind)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this earlier SO question

[How to say XAML <Button Height="Auto"/> in code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497921/how-to-say-xaml-button-height-auto-in-code-behind)

You set it to double.NAN

Comment: Should be double.NaN to be precise